# Why does For-Loop terminate all the codes after itself?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, c-strings, string-literals

After the for-loop finishes printing myArray, it simply doesn't let any further code to progress anymore and returns the value -1073741819.

```
int main() {

char *myArray[]={"Carmaker1","Carmaker2","Carmaker3","Carmaker4","Carmaker5","Carmaker6"};

for ( int i = 0 ; myArray[i] != '\0' ; i++ ) {
    
    printf("%s ",*(myArray+i));
}
/*
.
.
.
.Some code here...
.
.
.
*/
```

Comment: In the expression `myArray[i] != '\0'`, why are you comparing a pointer with a character? If you want the poiner array to be zero terminated, you must make it zero terminated yourself, by adding a` NULL` at the end of the array. Then you should compare with `NULL` instead of '\0'.

Comment: the condition in the loop causes the program to crash. \0 In C is mostly used to indicate the termination of a character string NOT an array.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
myArray[i] != '\0'
```

is equivalent to

```
myArray[i] != NULL
```

But your array does not contain an element with the value NULL.

So either declare the array like

```
char *myArray[]={"Carmaker1","Carmaker2","Carmaker3","Carmaker4","Carmaker5","Carmaker6", NULL};
```

(appending an initializer with the value `NULL`) and use the loop

```
for ( int i = 0 ; myArray[i] != NULL ; i++ ) {
    
    printf("%s ",*(myArray+i));
}
```

Or you can append the array with an empty string like

```
char *myArray[]={"Carmaker1","Carmaker2","Carmaker3","Carmaker4","Carmaker5","Carmaker6", ""};
```

and write the loop like

```
for ( int i = 0 ; myArray[i][0] != '\0' ; i++ ) {
    
    printf("%s ",*(myArray+i));
}
```

Or using the current declaration of the array change the loop the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i!= sizeof( myArray ) / sizeof( *myArray ) ; i++ ) {
    
    printf("%s ",*(myArray+i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code has a bug, as suggested in the comments, you can fix your code as shown below,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char *myArray[]=  {"Carmaker1","Carmaker2","Carmaker3","Carmaker4","Carmaker5","Carmaker6", ""};

for ( int i = 0 ; *myArray[i] != '\0' ; i++ ) {printf("%d, %s \n",i, *(myArray+i)); }

}
```

Comment: I believe a `NULL`-terminated array is a better solution than an array terminated by an empty string. This is also how [`argv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) is terminated. However, you are right that this is the closest solution for the code the OP posted.